# Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs

Возникла проблема при подключении к `hdfs` через `java`.
Кажется какая то ошибка версий, пробовала разные варианты решения ничего не помогло.

**Код программы:**

```java
String url = "hdfs://c7301.ambari.apache.org:8020/file.txt";

FileSystem fs = null;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(url), conf, "admin");

    in = fs.open(new Path(url));

    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeStream(fs);
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4**
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
at Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Версия hadoop:
Hadoop 3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315

Если кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, буду благодарна за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема еще актуальна, попробуй поставить одну зависимость в pom.xml вместо всего, что стоит у тебя на hadoop:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Она уже содержит все необходимые зависимости: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/3.1.1